# Issues calling methods on web context objects in thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to call methods on web context objects such as #request and #response in my templates in thymeleaf 3.0.3 and Spring Boot 1.5.1.

I continually get errors like this:

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method method(java.lang.String) on null context object

Here is a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/endpoint", produces = "text/html")
public String customerServiceSignin(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("attr1", true); // show proper header
    uiModel.addAttribute("attr2", false);
    return "template";
}
```

and a template:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div>
<div style="...">

    <div class="errorblock" th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(#request.getAttribute('some_attr'))}" th:utext="${#request.getAttribute('some_other_attr')}"></div>

    <form name='f' action="action" method='POST'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username' value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                </td>
                <td><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

This is one example, but anywhere I attempt to do this I get these errors. Is there a piece I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out #request needed to be #httpServletRequest

Comment: That's right, but why? The documentation makes a reference to #request not #httpServletRequest.

Comment: It depends on thymeleaf version. In version 2 it seems to be #httpServletRequest: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-basic-objects and on version 3 #request: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-basic-objects - however, you claim you already use thymeleaf 3, so I'm not sure about the problem here. Maybe you're using older version than you think you are?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you should be using `#strings` and not `#string`.  The `#request` part looks fine.

Also, just some comments on your coding style, you could format:

```
<th:block th:if="${not #string.isEmpty(#request.getAttribute('some_attr'))}">
    <div class="errorblock" th:utext="${#request.getAttribute('some_other_attr')}"></div>
</th:block>
```

to simply be

```
<div th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(#request.getAttribute('some_attr'))}" class="errorblock" th:utext="${#request.getAttribute('some_other_attr')}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that style tip. Unfortunately I still get the same error and am pretty sure it is due to some issue with #request and other web context objects. This happens for any template I use the web context objects, even ones where I do not use #strings.

Comment: Hmm... well, I don't know where to go from here.  I've recreated the same code you have above and don't have any problems using #strings or #request / #response.  (Thymeleaf 3, spring boot 1.4.2)